# Issues in Implementing Karger's Min Cut Algorithm using Union-Find

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, montecarlo

I've implemented the Karger's algorithm using the Union-Find Datastructure using Path-Compression Heuristics and Union by Rank but I've run into a couple of issues

What I've basically done is, I run the algorithm N*N*log(N) time for a good estimate of the answer. However, I simply just don't get the answer for the MinCut. I pick a random edge each time which has 2 members the source 's' and the destination 'd'. If their parents are not equal, I merge them and reduce the count of the vertices, 'vcnt' which was initially equal to the original number of vertices. This process continues until the number of vertices left is 2. Finally, i find the parent of the source and destination of each edge and if they are ont equal, I increase the MinCut count. This repeats N*N*Log(N) times.

I've tried running my code with a lot of test data but I don't seem to be getting the Mincut Value, Especially for large data.

Could anyone help me out? Also, performance improvement suggestions are welcome. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class KragersMinCut
{
    static int n=200;//Number of Vertices
    static int[] u=new int[n];
    static int[]rank =new int[n];

    static class Edge //Edge which hols the source and destination
    {
        int s,d;//Source,Destination
        Edge(int s,int d)
        {
            this.s=s;
            this.d=d;
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeUnionFindData()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            u[i]=i;
            rank[i]=1;
        }
    }

    private static int FIND(int xx) //Finding Parent using Path-Compression Heuristics
    {
        if(u[xx]!=u[u[xx]])
        {
            u[xx]=FIND(u[xx]);
        }
        return u[xx];
    }

    private static boolean UNION(int x,int y) //Union by Order-by-Rank to create evenly balanced search trees
    {
    int px=FIND(x),py=FIND(y);
    if(rank[px]>rank[py])
    {
        int temp=px;
        px=py;
        py=temp;
    }
    else if(rank[px]==rank[py])
        rank[py]++;

    u[px]=py;
    return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ArrayList<Edge> EdgeList=new ArrayList<Edge>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            String x=br.readLine();
            ArrayList<Integer>al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int j=0;j<x.length();j++) //This loop is for parsing the input format
            {
                if(x.charAt(j)<48 || x.charAt(j)>57)
                    continue;

                int p=j;
                String input="";
                while(p!=x.length()&&(x.charAt(p)>=48 && x.charAt(p)<=57))
                {
                    input+=(x.charAt(p));
                    p++;
                }
                j=p;
                al.add(Integer.parseInt(input.trim())-1);
            }
            for(int j=1;j<al.size();j++)
            {
                EdgeList.add(new Edge(al.get(0),al.get(j)));//Source,Destination
            }
        }
        //Edge list ready
        int MinCut=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int q=0;q<(n*n)*Math.log(n);q++)//Running theta(n^2*ln(n)) times for a good estimate. Runs in about 20 secs
        {
            int vcnt=n;//Essentially n
            InitializeUnionFindData();
            while(vcnt>2)
            {
                Edge x=EdgeList.get((int)(Math.random()*(EdgeList.size()-1)+1));//Obtaining random valued element at index from EdgeList
                int s=x.s,d=x.d;
                int ps=FIND(s),pd=FIND(d);
                if(ps!=pd)//Contracting. Essentially making their parents equal
                {
                    UNION(s,d);
                    vcnt--;
                }
            }
            int CurrMinCutValue=0;
            for(Edge i:EdgeList)
            {
                int px=FIND(i.s),py=FIND(i.d);
                if(px!=py)//Since they belong to different Vertices
                {
                    CurrMinCutValue++;
                }
            }
            MinCut=Math.min(MinCut,CurrMinCutValue);//Finding Minimum cut of all random runs
        }
        System.out.println(MinCut);
    }
}
```

TestData: (Source Vertex-> Connected Vertices)

1 2 3 4 7

2 1 3 4

3 1 2 4

4 1 2 3 5

5 4 6 7 8

6 5 7 8

7 1 5 6 8

8 5 6 7

Answer: 4 | Expected Answer: 2

Link: http://ideone.com/QP62FN

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm suggests that **Every edge is equally likely to be selected for the merging**.

But your code never selects the edge at index 0.

So modify the line:

```
Edge x=EdgeList.get((int)(Math.random()*(EdgeList.size()-1)+1));
```

to this:

```
Edge x=EdgeList.get((int)(Math.random()*(EdgeList.size())));
```

Also because every **edge is listed twice** in the edge list:

**you should print the following**

```
System.out.println(MinCut/2);
```

Now it should work.

Comment: @bholagabbar OK, brother, now I get it. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: DONE. Brilliant Observation. Thank you so much :D

Comment: @bholagabbar by running the code on a small example.